# How do I make the "find" command not say the file directory and name when being used?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to make a find command find the line that says "1-Male;" in a file called "gender.txt" in the same directory. The problem is that the find command also echos a blank line and the directory of said gender.txt, and I want to know how do I get the find command to, you know, not say those two lines?

```
@echo off
color 0a
title Test #1
echo What gender do you want to be?
echo[
echo 1. Male
echo 2. Female
echo 3. Robot
echo[
choice /c 123 /n /m ">"
set index=%errorlevel%
find "%index%" "%cd%\gender.txt"
pause & exit /b
```

I should also probably say what's the contents in "gender.txt".

```
1-Male
2-Female
3-Robot
```

Comment: Use `findstr` instead of `find`

Comment: If `%cd%` does not contain 1,2 or 3: `find "%index%" "%cd%\gender.txt"|find "%index%"` or another approach `type "%cd%\gender.txt"|find "%index%"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Postill commented, you can do this using `findstr` instead of `find`

```
C> findstr 1-Male *.txt
foo.txt:1-Male

C> findstr /M 1-Male *.txt
foo.txt

C> findstr /N 1-Male *.txt
foo.txt:1:1-Male

C> findstr /N 1-Male foo.txt
1:1-Male

C> findstr 1-Male foo.txt
1-Male
```

I imagine at least one of those options delivers what you seek.

Bonus material : [Why are there both FIND and FINDSTR programs, with unrelated feature sets?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963) by Raymond Chen.

Basically `findstr` is what happens when a Microsoft engineer who is used to `grep` encounters `find`, is driven by exasperation to do better, but only implements 0.01% of `grep`.